# Compute $S_n(X;G)$ with $X=\mathbb{R}P^2$ and $G=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Consider $X=\mathbb{R}P^2$ and $G=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, I want to compute the cellular chain complex $S_{\ast}(X;G)$.

An element in $S_n(X;G)$ is of the form $\sum_{i=1}^n g_i\alpha_i$ with $g_i\in G$ and $\alpha_i:\Delta^n\to X$.

The result should be $$0\to G\to G\to G\to 0,$$ where every map is the zero map.

So how do we get this groups and the maps?

Comment: You rarely/never want to compute the chain groups:  they are free and huge.  Are you sure you want this and not the homology?

Comment: Yes, but in this case the result should be $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, so this is not that huge :)

Comment: Sorry, I want to compute the cellular chain complex!

Comment: Ah, okay, that's different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb R\mathrm P^2$ has a CW structure of three cells: $e_0,e_1,e_2$, where $e_i$ has dimension $i$.  The attachment map of $e_1$ maps both ends to $e_0$.  The attachment map of $e_2$ maps the boundary circle to the $1$-skeleton by a degree-two map.

The cellular chain complex has groups $S_n(\mathbb R\mathrm P^2;\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ generated by $e_n$, for $n=0,1,2$.  The other groups are trivial.

To compute the boundary maps in general, for the boundary map $\partial_n:S_n(\mathbb R\mathrm P^2;\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})\to S_{n-1}(\mathbb R\mathrm P^2;\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ with $n>1$, we make a matrix $(a_{ij})_{ij}$ recording the degree of the boundary map from the $j$th $n$-cell to the quotient of the $(n-1)$-skeleton collapsing everything but the $i$th $(n-1)$-cell.  The $n=1$ case is the same as for singular homology.  In the case of $\mathbb R\mathrm P^2$:

- Since the attachment map of $e_1$ maps both $S^0$ points to the same point, the boundary map is $0$, so the matrix is $[0]$.
- Since the attachment map of $e_2$ maps the boundary $S^1$ to the $1$-skeleton (an $S^1$) by a degree-2 map, the matrix is $[2]$, which with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is $[0]$.

Therefore, the cellular chain complex is $$0\to\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{0}\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{0}\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\to 0$$

Comment: Why is this getting downvoted?

Comment: Thank you very much! It wasn't downvoted by me.

Comment: Is there a simple picture or another way to see that the real projective plane has one 0 cell, one 1 cell and one 2 cell?

Comment: @R.A. Yes: $\mathbb RP^2$ is the quotient of $S^2$ by the antipodal map.  One simplification is that one can start with the northern hemisphere and the equator instead and then quotient the equator by the antipodal map, and one might see that the northern hemisphere in the quotient is attached by a degree-two map to this image circle.  Alternatively, think of $\mathbb RP^2$ as a Möbius strip with a disk attached along the boundary.  If you cut that Möbius strip along its core circle and attach that strip to a disk, then the space is equivalently a disk glued to a circle by a degree-2 map.

Comment: Another way is by Schubert cells.  A line in $\mathbb R^3$ is the span of a single vector, which can be represented as the span of a column vector.  By scaling the vector so that the last non-zero entry in the vector is 1, we get three forms of vectors, $(1,0,0),(*,1,0),(*,*,1)$.  The collection of vectors of these forms have the topology of the 0-cell, 1-cell, and 2-cell.  The trick is to see that the $(*,*,1)$ has a degree-two attachment map to $(*,*,0)$.